# Input field string combination

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently trying to figure this out. This is actually working but I'm thinking to add a <kbd>plus</kbd> button that will add an input field and render the same results. With that in mind, I think  it appears impossible to do with this basic code, is there any way to do this?

I have currently 6 input field which I'm trying to add <kbd>plus</kbd> button to add one more for every click.

I have two objectives here, First button (<kbd>combination One</kbd>) and Second Button (<kbd>combination Two</kbd>)

- For first button: for every input field it will concatenate with other input fields. e.g `input1` to `input2` `3` `4` `5`, `6` and so on. And adding prefix `1.` and `2.` because they have to appear in that exact order. Combinations may be repeated but with adding `1.` and `2`, it becomes a different outcome.
- For second button: it's almost the same with first button but without repeating the same combination of strings and combining an input field to itself.

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6v0nhd9t/) code:

CODE:

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
var input3 = document.getElementById('input3');
var input4= document.getElementById('input4');
var input5= document.getElementById('input5');
var input6= document.getElementById('input6');



function combinationOne() {
var button = document.getElementById('outcome');

   var str1 = "1. "+ input1.value +"/2. "+ input2.value +"<br>";
   var str2 = "1. "+ input1.value+"/2. "+ input3.value+"<br>";     
   var str3 = "1. "+input1.value +"/2. "+ input4.value+"<br>";    
   var str4 = "1. "+input1.value +"/2. "+ input5.value+"<br>";    
   var str5 = "1. "+input1.value +"/2. "+ input6.value+"<br>";  
   
   var str6 = "1. "+input2.value +"/2. "+ input1.value+"<br>";    
   var str7 = "1. "+input2.value +"/2. "+ input3.value+"<br>"; 
   var str8 = "1. "+input2.value +"/2. "+ input4.value+"<br>";   
   var str9= "1. "+input2.value +"/2. "+ input5.value+"<br>";
   var str10 = "1. "+input2.value +"/2. "+ input6.value+"<br>";

   var str11 = "1. "+input3.value +"/2. "+ input1.value+"<br>";    
   var str12 = "1. "+input3.value +"/2. "+ input2.value+"<br>"; 
   var str13 = "1. "+input3.value +"/2. "+ input4.value+"<br>";   
   var str14 = "1. "+input3.value +"/2. "+ input5.value+"<br>";
   var str15 = "1. "+input3.value +"/2. "+ input6.value+"<br>";

   var str16 = "1. "+input4.value +"/2. "+ input1.value+"<br>";    
   var str17 = "1. "+input4.value +"/2. "+ input2.value+"<br>"; 
   var str18 = "1. "+input4.value +"/2. "+ input3.value+"<br>";   
   var str19 = "1. "+input4.value +"/2. "+ input5.value+"<br>";
   var str20 = "1. "+input4.value +"/2. "+ input6.value+"<br>";

   var str21 = "1. "+input5.value +"/2. "+ input1.value+"<br>";    
   var str22 = "1. "+input5.value +"/2. "+ input2.value+"<br>"; 
   var str23 = "1. "+input5.value +"/2. "+ input3.value+"<br>";   
   var str24 = "1. "+input5.value +"/2. "+ input4.value+"<br>";
   var str25 = "1. "+input5.value +"/2. "+ input6.value+"<br>";

   var str26 = "1. "+input6.value +"/2. "+ input1.value+"<br>";    
   var str27 = "1. "+input6.value +"/2. "+ input2.value+"<br>"; 
   var str28 = "1. "+input6.value +"/2. "+ input3.value+"<br>";   
   var str29 = "1. "+input6.value +"/2. "+ input4.value+"<br>";
   var str30 = "1. "+input6.value +"/2. "+ input5.value+"<br>";
 
   var results1 = str1+
                  str2+
                  str3+
                  str4+
                  str5+
                  str6+
                  str7+
                  str8+
                  str9+
                  str10+
                  str11+
                  str12+
                  str13+
                  str14+
                  str15+
                  str16+
                  str17+
                  str18+
                  str19+
                  str20+
                  str21+
                  str22+
                  str23+
                  str24+
                  str25+
                  str26+
                  str27+
                  str28+
                  str29+
                  str30;

      
    document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML=results1;
    

}

function combinationTwo() {
var button = document.getElementById('outcome');
        var str31 = input2.value +"/"+ input1.value+"<br>";
        var str32 = input3.value +"/"+ input1.value+"<br>";
        var str33 = input4.value +"/"+ input1.value+"<br>";
        var str34 = input5.value +"/"+ input1.value+"<br>";
        var str35 = input6.value +"/"+ input1.value+"<br>";
        
        var str36 = input3.value +"/"+ input2.value+"<br>";
        var str37 = input4.value +"/"+ input2.value+"<br>";
        var str38 = input5.value +"/"+ input2.value+"<br>";
        var str39 = input6.value +"/"+ input2.value+"<br>";     
 
        var str40 = input4.value +"/"+ input3.value+"<br>";
        var str41 = input5.value +"/"+ input3.value+"<br>";
        var str42 = input6.value +"/"+ input3.value+"<br>";  

        var str43 = input5.value +"/"+ input4.value+"<br>";
        var str44 = input6.value +"/"+ input4.value+"<br>";
        
        var str45 = input6.value +"/"+ input5.value+"<br>";  


            var results2 = str31+
                    str32+
                    str33+
                    str34+
                    str35+
                    str36+
                    str37+
                    str38+
                    str39+
                    str40+
                    str41+
                    str42+
                    str43+
                    str44+
                    str45;

           document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML=results2;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="input1" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input2" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input3" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input4" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input5" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input6" />
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="combinationOne()">combination One</button>
<button onclick="combinationTwo()">combination Two</button>
<p id="outcome"></p>
```

Comment: This would be a great opportunity for you to learn about [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) :) The first combination is basically `for (let i=1; i<=6; i++) { for (let j=1; j<=6; j++) { if (i != j) { /* output combination */ } } }` and the second combination is basically `for (let i=1; i<=6; i++) { for {let j=i+1; j<6; j++) { /* output combination */ } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code which generates the output dynamically for "combination one". Take this as a starting point for "combination two".

```js
function combinationOne() {
   let result = '';
   const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
   for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       for (let j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
           if (i === j) continue;
           result += '1. ' + inputs[i].value + ' / 2. ' + inputs[j].value + '<br>';
       }
   }
   
   document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML = result; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="input1" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input2" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input3" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input4" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input5" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="input6" />
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="combinationOne()">combination One</button>
<p id="outcome"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved the 2nd one with this as basis. :)